# How to rotate coordinates by a set degree

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I have tried many variations to rotate coordinates by a point, but when using I call `rotateX(1, 0, degreesToRadians(45))`, I receive `[-0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865476]`. Wouldn't the correct response be `[1, 1]`?

If I use rounding to get `[-1,1]`, I still get `-1`, and not `1`. What am I doing wrong? How do I correctly calculate rotation?

A 45 degree line would look like:

```
* [0, 0]
 * [1, 1]
  * [2, 2]
   * [3, 3]
    * [4, 4]
```

My Code:

```js
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}


function rotateX(x, y, angle) {
  return [x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle), x * Math.sin(angle) + y * Math.cos(angle)]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as written works perfectly.

There's one thing wrong in your asked question. When you call `rotateX(1, 0, degreesToRadians(45))`, it returns the correct answer [0.707.., 0.707]. I just tried it in the console.

The other thing is understanding why that is correct. It should not be [1, 1], because that would have extended the length of the point instead of just rotating it. The goal of the function is to rotate in a circle, so changing the distance from the origin would be an incorrect result. You could think about it this way:

Using the Pythagorean theorem, the point [1, 0] is `sqrt(1 + 0) = 1` unit from the origin. If the answer after rotating was [1, 1], suddenly the point would be `sqrt(1+1) = 1.414` units from the origin. The correct result is what it gives you, [0.707..., 0.707...]. This is 1/2 the sqrt of 2, so it results in the perfect 1 unit from origin like it should.

If you still don't believe it, grab a ruler and some graph paper. Measure out a straight line to the right, and count the squares in the x axis. Then, rotate the ruler 45 degrees and count how many squares there are in the x. You will find that the second result is 0.707 times the first. This is a fundamental part of the way circles and trigonometry work.